# Как создать http.Client если access-token есть?

Tags: golang, oauth, youtube-api

Библиотека http://golang.org/x/oauth2
Есть ClientID, ClientSecret и access token который я получаю руками. Надо реализовать функцию

```
buildOAuthHTTPClient(scope string) (*http.Client, error)
```

Есть реализация только с получением через браузер.

```
config := &oauth2.Config{
ClientID:     cfg.Installed.ClientID,
ClientSecret: cfg.Installed.ClientSecret,
Scopes:       []string{scope},
Endpoint: oauth2.Endpoint{
  AuthURL:  cfg.Installed.AuthURI,
  TokenURL: cfg.Installed.TokenURI,
},
RedirectURL: redirectUri,
}
config.Client(oauth2.NoContext, token)
```

Кто уже разобрался с этой библиотекой помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

`Scope` определяет область деййствия `access token`-а. Если токен уже есть, то зачем вызывать функцию, которая на вход получает `scope`?
Реализуйте клиента, который посылает в заголовке токен и все.

Если вам нужет не `OAuth 2.0` в общем, а его частный случай использования с `Youtube API`, то вот здесь много кода по теме
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/go